# Extend object created by parent class

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have a couple of d3 charts that share quite a lot of functionality. However they do diverge in a several areas. I'm considering moving them to separate classes based off a parent class because the singular `buildChart` function's length has grown unmaintainable.

The problem I'm facing right now is that even though it seems pretty easy to override certain methods from the parent in some instances, it would be nice to have the parent build most of one setup object, which contains properties like tick intervals, display formats, etc, but have each child class add a few properties to that object.

I thought to do this in the following way:

```
class Chart {
  constructor({ svg, data, range }) {
    this.svg = svg;
    this.range = range;
    this.data = data;
    this.setDetails();
  }
  setDetails() {
    this.details = {
      sharedProp: "this property is shared"
    };
  }
  scaffoldChart() {
    /* initial d3 stuff */
  }
}

export class SimilarChartUno extends Chart {
  constructor({ svg, data, range }) {
    super({ svg, data, range });
    this.decorateDetails()
    super.scaffoldChart()
  }
  decorateDetails() {
    this.details = Object.assign(this.details, {
      someUniqueProp: 'prop for UNO a'
    })
  }
}

// instance details :

{
  "sharedProp": "this property is shared",
  "someUniqueProp": "prop for UNO A"
}
```

This seems to work, but I have not seen an example like this anywhere: Is there is a better pattern than this?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vn717w0om0)

Comment: `constructor({ svg, data, range })` i've never seen a syntax like this. I know this is not your question, but can you explain this or give me a buzzword that i can google it? :D

Comment: @messerbill It is kind of useless here since those three arguments are the only three I am passing to the constructor, however, if you pass a larger object but you only want certain properties of, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to pull them out within the function declaration's parameters list.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with doing it the way you are currently, but if you'd like to avoid adding methods you could alter your `SimilarChartUno` to be something like this:

```
class SimilarChartUno extends Chart {
  constructor({ svg, data, range }) {
    super({ svg, data, range });
    super.scaffoldChart()
  }
  setDetails() {
    super.setDetails();
    this.details.someUniqueProp = 'prop for UNO a';
  }
}
```

In this way, you've maintained inheritance. The `setDetails()` is invoked in the super constructor with the child implementation. Alternatively, you can still perform an `this.details = Object.assign(this.details, { complexObject: {} });` after the `super.setDetails();` call for more complex assignments.

Comment: Yes, this is how I had it at its first iterations, but changed the name `decorateDetails` because I thought having the same name as in the superclass was a little odd looking. Thanks for the feedback!